# Issue referencing a set that is the same as user input

Tags: python, reference

I am creating a program that creates a workout for the user. I have defined sets with exercises based on the muscle group. I then ask the user to input what muscle group they want to target. How can I get this user input to then reference the set? What I currently try to do just references the word itself and not the set.

```
Legs = {"squat", "calf raises", "hamstring curls", "deadlifts", "walking lunges"}
musclegroup = input('What muscle group would you like to target?  ')
for i in musclegroup:
```

How can I get the for loop to reference the set 'Legs' and not the user string?

Comment: The tag reference is not what you think it is.

Comment: You have two fine answers using a dictionary... I would use a `list` as value to your key thou rather than `set`. As you may want to squat more times during that routine. (And `set` removes extra entries so that all is unique.) Example: `workouts = { 'legs': ['squat', 'calf raises', 'hamstring curls', 'deadlifts', 'walking lunges', 'squat'] }`

Answer (score 1):

I would structure the data as a dictionary of sets. So in this case:

```
musclegroup_exercises = {
    "legs": {"squat", "calf raises", "hamstring curls", "deadlifts", "walking lunges"},
    "arms": {...},
    "core": {...},
    # etc
}
```

Now when you ask the user for input you can consult the dictionary:

```
musclegroup = input('What muscle group would you like to target?  ')
for exercise in musclegroup_exercises[musclegroup.lower()]:
    print(exercise)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need data structure to achieve this. Python dict may be helful in this.

```
workouts = {
    'legs': {"squat", "calf raises", "hamstring curls", "deadlifts", "walking lunges"},
    'hands': {'your', 'other', 'set', 'for', 'hands'}
}
musclegroup = input('What muscle group would you like to target?  ')

print(workouts[musclegroup.lower()]]
```